# Changing symbol and legend of feature class in ArcMap using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects

I want to change the symbol of features and legend programmatically.  When I use this code

```
Dim pSymbolSelector As ISymbolSelector
Set pSymbolSelector = New SymbolSelector
Dim pMarker As ISimpleMarkerSymbol
Set pMarker = New SimpleMarkerSymbol
If Not pSymbolSelector.AddSymbol(pMarker) Then
       MsgBox "Could not add symbol"
ElseIf pSymbolSelector.SelectSymbol(0) Then
       Dim pSymbol As ISymbol
       Set pSymbol = pSymbolSelector.GetSymbolAt(0)
End If
```

then Symbol Selector is open, but when I select a symbol it is not being applied at the current layer in Table of Contents.

Answer (score 3):

According to the ESRI documentation: "The SymbolSelector class is used for presenting the user with a choice of symbols: marker, line, fill, or text. The symbols in the selector are taken from the currently referenced style files."

If you want to handle this task programmatically, without user input, you can use [IFeatureRenderer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000004wn000000).

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur response...But when i run the above code it open Symbol selector of only single type it does not change it for polyline or polygon type featureclass.. it means it shows only point type symbols not for polyline and polygon type.what should i do for that..

Comment: You're using 'ISimpleMarkerSymbol', which will give you a point marker. The code you posted is for point symbols, not line/polygon. IFeatureRenderer is still your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the interface `ISimpleFillSymbol`.